# How to install Kali Metapackages manually?

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

I had an issue installing Kali Linux on Virtual Machine.
So I only selected "Xfce (Kali's default desktop environment)" in Software Selection Option.

As you can see the options in this [IMAGE](https://www.kali.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/release-2020.2-setup.png).

Now, how can I install manually these:

1. default -- recommended tools (available in the live system)
2. Collection of tools [Selecting this item has no effect]
3. top10 -- the 10 most popular tools

(The above options are written as show in the image)

Please help me out here. Thank You.

Comment: First you can download Kali Linux lite ISO image from their official website. Now you can create a virtual machine from that in virtual box. Then you can install Katoolin package and install all kali packages manually. Or you can run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` then install packages you like. I.E. `sudo apt install nmap air rack-ng etc.etc`

Answer (score 0):

try to install gnome desktop gui, i think is enabled by default when you install it:

> sudo apt install kali-desktop-core kali-desktop-gnome

those are the most commonly used tools:

> sudo apt install kali-tools-802-11 kali-tools-wireless kali-tools-web kali-tools-exploitation